# MongoDB Cache common part of aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a backend HTTP route that computes several stats about a user with aggregations. I nearly always start those with a common base so that I have enough information to work with.

They all start something like this:

```js
Infos.aggregate([
  { $match: { owner: user._id } },
  { $lookup: { from: 'tracks', localField: 'trackId', foreignField: 'id', as: 'track' }},
  { $unwind: '$track' },
```

> I have already indexed all the needed fields in my database (here `id` in `tracks`)

The lookup is necessary since I then filter based on the the `track`. The problem here is that for the moment the user has 10.000 `Infos`, and the lookup takes around 2300ms in total as quoted in the `.explain()` of the requests:

```js
{
  '$cursor': [Object],
  nReturned: 14695,
  executionTimeMillisEstimate: 92
},
{
  '$lookup': [Object],
  nReturned: 14695,
  executionTimeMillisEstimate: 2473
},
{
  '$match': [Object],
  nReturned: 585,
  executionTimeMillisEstimate: 2505
},
{
  '$unwind': [Object],
  nReturned: 585,
  executionTimeMillisEstimate: 2505
},
```

I would like to know if there is a known good practice to cache the first steps of this aggregation for a specific user so that while no `Infos` is added, my queries will use this cache instead of re-computing every time.

Thanks